# TabLayout icons by using resource files

Tags: android, icons, android-tablayout

I wanted to create tabs aligned at the top. I was wondering if it was possible to add the icons which are listed in items within the `menu.xml` by using the `app:menu/top_home_menu`. If not is there any simpler way than just `TabLayout.getTabAt(index).setIcon(directory)`?

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop = "true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:background="@drawable/white_grey_boarder_top"
                app:menu="@menu/top_home_menu">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

I thought it like how bottomnavigationbar could add the icons through making seperate menu

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavViewBar"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_boarder_top"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">

        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

In new version of TabLayout, google added TabItem which easily can add Icon through your XML with following code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
     app:tabMode="fixed"
     app:tabBackground="@color/red"
     app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple"
     app:tabPadding="2dp"
     app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
     app:tabMinWidth="64dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

 <!--add height and width to TabItem -->
 <android.support.design.widget.TabItem 
         android:text="@string/tab_text"/>

 <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
         android:icon="@drawable/ic1"/>
```

Please refer this link for more information [link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout)

**Hope this wil help**

Comment: Hi so I wanted to create a seperate menu for the items that contains links to the icons and wanted to know if i could add these through the xml easily by creating it seperate

Comment: or you can add icon using   tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);

Comment: Not exactly what I want but Thank you.